# Section for official use only

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to know how to create a field that is visible to the user yet not allow them to input anything to the field except if an authorised user.

Eg. The Section for "Official Use only."

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms.  I think that you are asking for field level permissions that would allow only certain users to fill out certain fields.  Cognito Forms does not offer that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a section that only shows once you enter in a password correctly.  Details below are how we use the form in this manner.

Add a field with a mask value, limit the number of characters.
Then add a password field where the default value is your password, is always read only and never shown.
Then set your section to show if the password entered = the password.

```
=(Form.StaffUseOnly = Form.Password)
```